# GIT Symbolic Reference (Alias) on remote Repository branch?

Tags: git, branch, alias

Is there any way to push an alias created locally to a remote repository?

I have checked out the remote branch  v1.0.

I have created the alias (green_horn) to the local copy like this:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/green_horn refs/heads/v1.0
```

Can I push it back to the remote, so that this link would be available for other user checking out from remote the next time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The transfer protocols do not support symbolic references in any significant and useful way.  The `HEAD` symbolic reference has partial support in newer versions of Git, through `git remote set-head`, but only in the "obtain information from remote" direction, not in the "send information to remote" direction.

This is not actually a big loss, as symbolic references are really only well-behaved for the special name `HEAD`.  In particular, if you ask Git to delete your example `green_horn` name, it will delete `v1.0` rather than `green_horn`!  (I consider this a bug myself, but I'm not sure if the Git maintainers think of it as a bug or a feature.)

In order to set or manipulate a symbolic reference, then, you must have some other form of access to the remote.  This is why, for instance, GitHub provides a non-Git interface (browser / REST API) to adjust the target of the `HEAD` symbolic reference of a GitHub-hosted repository.

---

Terminology note: That's not an *alias* (which in Git refers specifically to `git alias` and the `[alias]` configuration section), it's a *symbolic reference*.  (I was a bit confused until I read through the entire question, since you do call it both things.)